# Can not override Magento/Checkout/Model/DefaultConfigProvider.php file

Tags: checkout, magento-2.1, overrides, model

I want to change a file in `Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider` file

I am trying to change data in function but I can not override funciton Where I am going to Wrong.

I have Created a File `etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider" type="Test\Sales\Model\Checkout\DefaultConfigProvider" />
</config>
```

I want to change or override function `getTotalsData()`

Created File in `app/code/Test/Sales/Model/Checkout/DefaultConfigProvider.php`

```
<?php
namespace Test\Sales\Model\Checkout;

class DefaultConfigProvider extends Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider
{

    private function getTotalsData()
    {
        die('override');
       // Override stuff
    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

As I understand your goal is to change config.
You don't need to overwrite whole class for this.
You can create `after` plugin for config modification.

Take a look onto
`\Magento\Persistent\Model\Checkout\ConfigProviderPlugin::afterGetConfig()`

Comment: I tried but not working I want to add new product attribute  in totals items array therefore I want to modify getConfig() function but not working using plugin concept

Answer (score 0):

You are missing slash before `Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider` class.

In your php class,

```
class DefaultConfigProvider extends Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider
{
```

Replace with,

```
class DefaultConfigProvider extends \Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider
{
```

Remove var folder and check again.

Comment: Ok let me check 1 min

Comment: please let me know if have issue,

Comment: I clear cache and remove var/generation folder but not working

Comment: I can override other model files but this one not working

Comment: You cant overrider private function so its not working for your case.

Comment: any solution in this scenario ?

Comment: Ok If I copy whole function getConfig() method in my override file so I can not  and in check page it display blanks and error in console abot 'captcha' and 'autocomplete' so what I do.help me in this scenario

Answer (score 0):

This is code i use to rewrite it, you can take a look

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider">
        <plugin name="custom_defaultconfigprovider" type="Test\Sales\Plugin\DefaultConfigProvider" />
    </type>
</config>
```

In file **Test/Sales/Plugin/DefaultConfigProvider.php**

```
<?php
namespace Test\Sales\Plugin;

class DefaultConfigProvider
{
    public function afterGetConfig($subject, $result)
    {
        if (isset($result['totalsData']) && $result['totalsData']) {
            $custom = // add your custom here;
            $result['totalsData'] = $custom;
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: so totalsData is the total summary? i have given some custom value there, but its not updated

Comment: totalsData is variable in vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/DefaultConfigProvider.php function getConfig() , you can see in it

Answer (score 0):

Create the file app/code/Company/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml with content :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="defaultConfigProviders" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="custom" xsi:type="object">Company\Module\Model\DefaultConfigProvider</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Then create model file app/code/Company/Module/Model/DefaultConfigProvider.php :

```
namespace Company\Module\Model;

class DefaultConfigProvider
{
    public function afterGetConfig($subject, $result)
    {
        if (isset($result['totalsData']) && $result['totalsData']) {
            $custom = // add your custom here;
            $result['totalsData'] = $custom;
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```